# UIPopoverController not dismissing

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

In my app I have this hierarchy:

AppViewController (root)-->HUDViewController (as a container viewcontroller within AVC)-->NavBar (subview of UIView)-->UIButtons

When you touch some of the buttons they need to launch a UIPopoverController from AVC. I send a notification back from the NavBar class to AVC. In the selector for the notification center I have this code

```
 ...
 //get the client list from the notification
            [dictPopoverData setObject: [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"Client List"] forKey:@"Client List"];

            //get the frame of the object launching the popover
            popupCallerFrame = CGRectFromString([[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"Caller Frame"]);

            [self presentPopOver:CLIENT_LIST:YES:dictPopoverData];
...
```

then in presentPopOver I have this:

```
- (void) presentPopOver : (int) popoverID : (BOOL) isTable : (NSMutableDictionary*) dictPopoverData {

    if (self.myPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.myPopoverController = nil;
    }

    CGRect launchFrame;

    //init the popover
    if (popoverID == CLIENT_LIST) {

        ClientListPopover* vcClientList = [[ClientListPopover alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        vcClientList.arrDataSource = [dictPopoverData objectForKey:@"Client List"];
        self.myPopoverViewController = vcClientList;

        //set the launch frame
        launchFrame = popupCallerFrame;
        launchFrame.origin.x = launchFrame.origin.x;
        launchFrame.origin.y = launchFrame.origin.y + 100.0;


    } else if (popoverID == PA_LIST) {

        PAListPopover* vcPAList = [[PAListPopover alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        vcPAList.strClientNumber = [dictPopoverData objectForKey:@"Client Number"];
        self.myPopoverViewController = vcPAList;

        //set the launch frame
        launchFrame = popupCallerFrame;
        launchFrame.origin.x = launchFrame.origin.x;
        launchFrame.origin.y = launchFrame.origin.y + 100.0;
    }


    //init and display the popover controller
    if (self.myPopoverController == nil) {

        //add the self.myPopoverViewController
        self.myPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.myPopoverViewController];

        //display the popover
        [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:launchFrame inView:self.view
          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                          animated:YES];
        [self.myPopoverController setDelegate:self];

    } else {

        [self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.myPopoverController = nil;
    }



}
```

So what is suppose to happen is the user clicks the client button, notification gets sent to AVC, a UITable in a popover controller is presented. The user then selects a client from the table. Again, a notification is sent to AVC, the displayed client list popover should now be dismissed and the PA list popover should show. It seems that [self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES] is not being called. I've traced it and it hits that line of code but nothing happens, the first popover remains on the screen. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Edit: I forgot to mention I can't seem to assign a delegate to self.myPopoverController. Which is probably why the dismiss method is not firing.

Edit: I added the call to the delegate after the popover controller is inited. That didn't seem to make a difference. If I touch outside the first popover, without touching inside, it does dismiss and I can trace the method.

Comment: So if you tap the button is not taking you to the else conditional? Or it takes you to the else conditional but the dismissPopoverAnimated is not dismissing the popOver put a breakpoint just at [self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; Then from there print in your console po self.myPopoverController.delegate and check that the delegate is not nill

Comment: That: dismissPopoverAnimated is not dismissing - if I log the popover controller delegate it's there - <AppViewController: 0x8d7b0b0>

Comment: I traced it and on the second call it is hanging on the displayPopoverFromRect call.

Comment: Dang it. The error had nothing to do with the popover controller...I had a typo in the second view controller that was causing an endless loop...if you come back put - Try not being stupid as an answer I'll select it. : D

Comment: lol ya that has happened to me before